# Bulk API error Failed to write query result, while querying the opportunity

Tags: salesforce

BulkBatchFailed: Batch 751500000079GEPAA2 of job 75050000005pAvmAAE failed: InternalServerError : Failed to write query result

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SOQL with WHERE clauses ? I suspect that the SOQL query which you tried to execute was not that selective and hence it took long time to query.

Please check this blog and see if you can refine your SOQL query. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_VLSQ.htm

Hope this helps.

Comment: same query is running fine with soap api. sometimes its giving the result using bulk api, sometimes its failing with above error

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I was querying the VersionData field from the ContentVersion object.  Once I removed this field from my query the error went away.

If you are not querying the ContentVersion field I would try the same query with just the Id field and see if that works.  If so you know there is a field you are not supposed to query for in the way you are querying it.